# Python/Beautifulsoup/Parsing

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup

I have a question about Beautifulsoup parsing. As you can see below, I want to get the title from 'li' tag.(in white box) Can anyone tell me how to do it?
Here is my code. Thank you.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = urlopen('https://movie.naver.com/movie/running/current.nhn')
soup = BeautifulSoup(url, 'html.parser')

data = soup.find('ul', {'class':'top_thumb_lst'})

print(data)
```

[image]

Comment: Please include a _readable_ fragment of the HTML document, as well as the output of `print(data)`.

Comment: I saved the data but I don't know how to get it to you. there is no option for me to upload it here.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean you want to extract the first `data-title` attribute? try `data.find('li')['data-title']`. The full code is:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = urlopen('https://movie.naver.com/movie/running/current.nhn')
soup = BeautifulSoup(url, 'html.parser')

data = soup.find('ul', {'class': 'top_thumb_lst'})

print(data.find_all('li')[0]['data-title'])
```

The result is

```
앤트맨과 와스프
```

OR if you wanna get all content with `data-title` attribute, then use `data.find_all('li')` instead. The full code should be:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = urlopen('https://movie.naver.com/movie/running/current.nhn')
soup = BeautifulSoup(url, 'html.parser')

data = soup.find('ul', {'class': 'top_thumb_lst'})

for item in data.find_all('li'):
    print(item['data-title'])
```

It will give you the result:

```
앤트맨과 와스프
마녀
변산
탐정: 리턴즈
허스토리
미드나잇 선
쥬라기 월드: 폴른 킹덤
오션스8
시카리오: 데이 오브 솔다도
오 루시!
바르다가 사랑한 얼굴들
개들의 섬
잉글랜드 이즈 마인
빅샤크: 매직체인지
여중생A
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. You saved my day.

Comment: You are welcome. Accept this answer would be much more helpful.

Comment: I did. I will give you the thumbs up.